# Excel Interop + MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel-interop

Is it safe to use Excel Interop inside MVC app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## EPPlus

#### EPPlus is a .net library that reads and writes Excel 2007/2010 files using the Open Office Xml format (xlsx).

It does not require Excel to be installed on the server.  It doesn't use Excel libraries, it is just an API interface to the Open Office XML format (xlsx).  XLSX is actually just a a zip file with a folder structure and xml files inside to describe the layout and data of the spreadsheet.

[epplus.codeplex.com](http://epplus.codeplex.com).  The codeplex site has tons of examples plus here's an [additional blogpost](http://zeeshanumardotnet.blogspot.com/2011/06/creating-reports-in-excel-2007-using.html) with more.

*Just putting this here as an Actual answer.*

Comment: Does EPPlus work with calculations in cells? Also does it require Excel to be installed on the computer? The documentation on their website doesn't answer these questions.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean ASP.NET MVC trying to run Excel on the server, the answer is that it's not recommended. Excel is really designed as a desktop app, so running it on a server can cause some problems, as described on in this [MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).

If you can target Excel 2007/2010, a good alternative is to use the Open Office XML libraries to create, read or modify Excel workbooks without instantiate and Excel instance. Take a look at [www.openxmldeveloper.org](http://www.openxmldeveloper.org)

Comment: You can also use Epplus (http://epplus.codeplex.com/).